# Why would any body use this pattern?

Tags: javascript

I read this once in a script, but I didn't understand its benefits.

```
(function () {}).call(this);
```

Also, I tried running it,

```
(function () { console.log('Hello World') }).call(this);
```

but it didn't print anything.

Even calling this `(function () { console.log('Hello World')  })()` didn't print anything either. Whats wrong?

Comment: It will print Hello World when you run it , just tried it on firebug console .

Comment: I ran it on the console ..  but nothing got printed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dublinan/QvJJt/

For example, if you open this page in google chrome, then right click anywhere on the page and inspect element -> console, u can see the output.

Comment: That is sane code. If you run it in your browser's console, it will print Hello World.

Comment: Works fine for me. It's a [Self-Executing Anonymous Function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the writer wants to change the context of the IIFE. Passing `this` would be pointless, since it will refer to `window` even without the `call`.

Something like this would change the meaning of `this` in the scope:

```
(function () { console.log('Hello World', this) }).call({foo:1});
```

However, I still don't see the point, since you might as well do it like this:

```
(function (fooObj) { console.log('Hello World', fooObj) })({foo:1});
```

Which I would say is more common to see.

Comment: You're assuming it's executed in the global environment.

Comment: @cookiemonster Well, without any better explanation from OP, one can only assume that it's the case

Comment: Why? There's no need to make such assumptions. As for the second part of your answer, consider that JS is getting new function syntax which has a lexically defined `this`, which would make the enclosing `this` value potentially important.

Comment: @cookiemonster Regardless, you could still pass `this` as an argument to the IIFE. Using `call` to invoke something which is already self-invoking is wrong.

Comment: It's very far from being "wrong". And with the new function syntax, it would be necessary if you want the functions to have the enclosing `this` value. Passing as an argument wouldn't help.

Comment: @cookiemonster If you insist on using the `this` keyword instead of an argument - then sure. Functionality-wise = no difference.

Comment: `this` to me means the `context` and so can be descriptively useful when compared to a standard variable `foo`, which would not necessarily denote itself as the `context`, even if there is functionally no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I use `this` when I want my code to work in either a browser window (in which case `this` refers to `window`) *or* a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) (in which case `this` refers to the worker instance).

The `.call(this)` works well for this, though of course you could do it differently. For example, this would also work:

```
(function(root) {

    root.MyLibrary = MyLibrary;

}(this));
```

As always, there's more than one way to skin the proverbial cat.

Comment: In a `webworker` it would be refering to `self`, would it not?

Comment: @Xotic750 From my experience in a web worker `self` and `this` refer to the same (worker) object. To be honest I'm not sure why they introduced `self`...

Comment: Perhaps something to do with `"use strict";`? :/